# Pygame mouse speed

Tags: python, pygame, mouse

I am new to coding and pygame and I am looking for the code to check if the mouse is travelling at a certain speed. And if it is, then to quit the game.

```
if the mouse speed is greater than say 10 pixels per second
     Run = False
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `MOUSEMOTION` event has an attribute `rel` which represents how much the mouse has moved relative to its previous position. Using this attribute, we can calculate the speed by using Pythagoras theorem (`**` means power in Python). So in your event loop, you can do the following:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
        dx, dy = event.rel
        speed = (dx ** 2 + dy ** 2) ** (1/2)  # Pythagoras theorem.
        if speed >= MAX_SPEED:
            quit()  # Or show quit screen or whatever.
```

Make sure to define `MAX_SPEED` before the loop (as a global variable for example).

One problem with this approach is that the first event will have a relative position to origin, i.e. if your mouse is at (100, 100) when the game starts, the `rel` attribute will be (100, 100).

Since you probably don't want to enforce your game rule right at the beginning of your application, this shouldn't be a problem. However, if you want the game to open up with this rule enforced, you would need to skip the first `MOUSEMOTION` event. This can be done by checking a boolean.

```
# Define this globally (or somewhere where it will only be set on startup).
# Also, use a better name than 'first'. Something that represent the logic for your game. 
first = False


for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
        dx, dy = event.rel
        speed = (dx ** 2 + dy ** 2) ** (1/2)  # Pythagoras theorem.
        if speed >= MAX_SPEED and first:
            quit()  # Or show quit screen or whatever.
        first = True
```

Answer (score 0):

Every frame you could track the mouse position via the `pygame.mouse.get_pos()` function, when it changes, check the time from `pygame.time.get_ticks()`.

Something like:

```
MAX_SPEED = 50

previous_mouse_position = None
previous_sample_time    = None
...

current_mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
if ( previous_mouse_position != current_mouse_pos ):
    # mouse has moved
    pixels_movement = distance( previous_mouse_position, current_mouse_pos )
    time_now        = pygame.time.get_ticks()
    movement_time   = ( time_now - previous_sample_time ) / 1000  # milliseconds -> seconds
    movement_speed = pixels_movement / movement_time
    if ( movement_speed > MAX_SPEED ):
        doSomething()

elif ( previous_mouse_position == None ):
    # No previous recorded position
    previous_mouse_position = current_mouse_pos
    previous_sample_time    = pygame.time.get_ticks()
```

Of course the [euclidian distance between two points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance#Two_dimensions) can be computed fairly easily.

EDIT:

```
import math

def distance( point1, point2 ):
    """ Return the Euclidian distance between two points 
        Ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance#Two_dimensions """
    # NOTE: this code hasn't been tested
    p1x, p1y  = point1
    p2x, p2y  = point2
    x_squared = ( p2x - p1x ) * ( p2x - p1x )
    y_squared = ( p2y - p1y ) * ( p2y - p1y )
    pixel_dist= math.sqrt( x_squared + y_squared )
    return pixel_dist
```

Comment: Hi there, thank you so much, I added it into my code but for some reason it says the name "distance" is not defined, could you help me out?

Comment: @RobinRates - I left `distance()` as an exercise for the reader ;)     I think I have one lying around, I'll make an edit.